# TypeError: Cannot set property 'brief_title' of null - node and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, api, mongoose, ejs

I have an app using Node/Express/Mongo and I'm running into trouble when I want to edit a document. I can add documents no problem but when I built out the Edit form I get the error in the title. I can fetch the document as well and see the information I've put in. The problem is when I try to save whatever changes I've made.

Here's my edit function: The error occurs at the brief.brief_title = updated_brief_title in the FindByIdAndUpdate method.

```
 exports.postEditBrief = (req, res, next) => {
    const briefId = req.body.briefId;
    const updated_brief_title = req.body.brief_title;
    const updated_country = req.body.country;
    const updated_psg = req.body.psg;
    const updated_one_year_withholding = req.body.one_year_withholding;
    const updated_withholding_only = req.body.withholding_only;
    const updated_practice_advisory = req.body.practice_advisory;
    const updated_courthouse = req.body.courthouse;
    const updated_pages = req.body.pages;
    const updated_additional_psg = req.body.additional_psg;
    const updated_gangs = req.body.gangs;
    const updated_gang_name = req.body.gang_name;
    const updated_link = req.body.link;

Brief.findByIdAndUpdate(briefId)
  .then(brief => {
    brief.brief_title = updated_brief_title;
    brief.country = updated_country;
    brief.psg = updated_psg;
    brief.one_year_withholding = updated_one_year_withholding;
    brief.withholding_only = updated_withholding_only;
    brief.practice_advisory = updated_practice_advisory;
    brief.courthouse = updated_courthouse;
    brief.pages = updated_pages;
    brief.additional_psg = updated_additional_psg;
    brief.gangs = updated_gangs;
    brief.gang_name = updated_gang_name;
    brief.link = updated_link;
    return brief.save();
  })
  .then(result => {
      console.log(Brief);
  res.redirect('/');
})
.catch(err => console.log(err)); 
};
```

I've played around with the various "find and update" methods in Mongoose but the results are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `object` of the data you want to update and pass it as a second argument in the function, when you do `.then()` it gets you the result of the operation you are doing and you don't need to call `.save()` as it does that internally

Correct version should look something like this

```
exports.postEditBrief = (req, res, next) => {
    const briefId = req.body.briefId;
    let update = {
      brief_title: req.body.brief_title,
      country: req.body.country,
      psg: req.body.psg,
      one_year_withholding: req.body.one_year_withholding,
      withholding_only: req.body.withholding_only,
      practice_advisory: req.body.practice_advisory,
      courthouse: req.body.courthouse,
      pages: req.body.pages,
      additional_psg: req.body.additional_psg,
      gangs: req.body.gangs,
      gang_name: req.body.gang_name,
      link: req.body.link
    }

    Brief.findByIdAndUpdate(briefId, update)
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.redirect('/');
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```

You can simplify it even further using `object destructuring`.

**Update:**

You need to use `$set` with `findOneandUpdate` if you don't want to overwrite your document

```
exports.postEditBrief = (req, res, next) => {
        const briefId = req.body.briefId;
        let update = {
          brief_title: req.body.brief_title,
          country: req.body.country,
          psg: req.body.psg,
          one_year_withholding: req.body.one_year_withholding,
          withholding_only: req.body.withholding_only,
          practice_advisory: req.body.practice_advisory,
          courthouse: req.body.courthouse,
          pages: req.body.pages,
          additional_psg: req.body.additional_psg,
          gangs: req.body.gangs,
          gang_name: req.body.gang_name,
          link: req.body.link
        }
    
        Brief.findOneAndUpdate(briefId, {$set:update})
          .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.redirect('/');
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      };
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working better but the findByIdAndUpdate method isn't saving to the database. The 'result' in the console is null. 

findByOneAndUpdate does save to the database but is ovewriting ID's so as soon as I change a document it resets that ID to the very first document I have instead changing the doc itself.